# C++ template partial explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, partial-specialization

Can we partially instantiate a C++ template explicitly?

```
template class <typename T, int N>
class MyClass {
  ...
};

template<int N> class MyClass<int, N>;  // not meant for specification
template<int N> class MyClass<float, N>;
```

just like we can have:

```
template class <typename T>
class MyClass {
  ...
};

template class MyClass<int>;
template class MyClass<float>;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A template is not a class. It's a template. (A blueprint to build a class). It can only become a class when all template parameters are accounted for.

having written this (typo corrected):

```
template <typename T, int N>
class MyClass {

};
```

You may by all means do this:

```
template<int N> class MyClass<int, N>;  
template<int N> class MyClass<float, N>;
```

But it is not instantiating a template (because that has no meaning), nor is it instantiating a concrete class formed from that template. What it is actually doing is forward-declaring the existence of a partially specialised (possibly infinite) subset of the the template.

You may also do this:

```
template<int N> class MyClass<int, N> {};  
template<int N> class MyClass<float, N> {};
```

Which has partially specialised `MyClass` for `<int, [all values of N]>` and `<float, [all values of N]>`.

However, this template subset is still not instantiated. Merely *defined*.

to actually instantiate a template, whether partially specialised or not, we must name it, accounting for all template arguments.

Comment: Are you willing to explain also why the same technique does not work for function templates? (pretty please)

Comment: @Vroomfondel I think it's to do with the fact that functions have overloads already, and partial specialisation would not play well with overload resolution.